# Two networks with same SSID, different credentials

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, hotspot, ssid

(Laptop running W7.)
We have a wireless network all around the campus with SSID X, which requires credentials Y. The same wireless network exists in my faculty (at least the SSID is the same), where is requires credentials Y' (different than Y).

The problem is that Windows treats this as one network, which is uncomfortable since if I'll connect to the network in one place, Windows will remember my credentials, and then when I'll go to the other place, those credentials will be incorrect (as I said, each place requires different credentials). So in order to deal with this I have to go the network's properties, choose 'Advanced Settings', then 'Replace Credentials', etc... Of course this is a never-ending cycle.

Does anyone have any suggestions? (E.g. a way to force Windows to differentiate between the networks, or some more sophisticated login mechanism, or anything else.) A big thanks in advance.

P.S. Maybe the title is misleading and this actually counts as one network, frankly I'm not sure.

Comment: It is really bad practice to have multiple networks with the same SSID. You should complain to your network administrator and ask them to change this, unless they have a very good reason for this, but even then its bad practice. Either they should rename the SSID's so they're unique everywhere, or make all settings including the password the same at all places so the network can automatically switch between access points.

Comment: This is not a Windows problem. I never use Windows myself and I too have run into similar problems with identical SSID on different networks. I agree with everything @LPChip said about the proper solution. And maybe that should have been posted as an answer rather than a comment.